# SQL Server: error when connecting

Tags: networking, sql-server, sql-server-2008

(migrated from stackoverflow)

The application I'm using tries to connect SQL Server named instance running on a dedicated database server. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
The TCP/IP connection to the host <instance_name>, port 1433 has failed. Error: Connection refused: connect.
```

Is the firewall blocking my access or what? Should I dedicate a different port for this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows firewall would be a place to check. SQL Server uses port 1433 as the default port. There could be a whole lot of other reasons involved as well. But start with the firewall.